# How to remove character from a given DataTable column?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a column `TOTAL_DOLLARS` that holds `String` values that I want to convert to `Decimal`.  However, these values also have a `$` character preceding them (as they are dollar amounts).  I want to remove this `$` character, though I can't quite find a method to do so.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
For Each row As DataRow In myTable.Rows
    Replace(row.Item("TOTAL_DOLLARS"), "$", "")
Next
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to preserve data integrity on your "TOTAL_DOLLARS" column, simply add a new column of the desired type and loop through to fill it:

```
myTable.Columns.Add("Total", GetType(Decimal))
For Each row As DataRow In myTable.Rows
    row("Total") = Convert.ToDecimal(row("TOTAL_DOLLARS").ToString.Replace("$", ""))
Next
```

or like this (to preserve NULLs):

```
myTable.Columns.Add("Total", GetType(Decimal))
For Each row As DataRow In myTable.Rows
    If Not IsDBNull(row("TOTAL_DOLLARS")) Then
        row("Total") = Convert.ToDecimal(row("TOTAL_DOLLARS").ToString.Replace("$", ""))
    Else
        row("Total") = System.DBNull.Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks!  It is saying that my `input string is not in the correct format`, but I assume that's an issue on my end.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your TOTAL_DOLLARS column contains values that are strings the following should do the job:

```
For Each row As DataRow In myTable.Rows
    Dim dollarsInRow As Decimal
    dollarsInRow = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Item("TOTAL_DOLLARS").Replace("$", String.Empty))
Next
```