# Import to DataTable using OleDB/Jet

Tags: .net, vb.net, jet

I wrote a short function with Oledb which should read large amount of data but there are still several issues I couldnt't solve, it's about reading and inserting semicolon separated data in sql database

```
Private Function GetCSVFile(ByVal file As String) As DataTable

        Try
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & TextBox1.Text & ";Extended Properties=""TEXT;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
            Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr)

            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from " & _table & ".csv", conn)
            da.Fill(dt)
            Application.DoEvents()
            getData = dt
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return getData
    End Function
```

1. it reads whole file but i need to tell the function that it should read only 50.000 rows and pass them to another function step for step, it should probably better work in for loop because jet oledb doesn't read files larger than 1 GB

2. i need to replace characters

```
    value(i) = value(i).Replace("\t", Constants.vbTab).Replace("\n", Constants.vbLf).Replace("\r", Constants.vbCr).Replace("\""", """").Replace("\\", "\")
```

but it usually works only for strings

3. I need to recognize data types like integer, double, string etc. my first idea was to do it over sql query and check the tables over tryparse

   ```
     Dim dtInserts As DataTable = db.GetDataTable("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM " & _table)
               Dim ListOfTypes As New List(Of System.Type)
        For Each _col As DataColumn In dtInserts.Columns
                   Dim _type As System.Type = _col.DataType
                   ListOfTypes.Add(_type)
               Next
               Dim _wert1 As String = "11.11.2011"
               Dim _type1 As System.Type = ListOfTypes.Item(1)
               If DateTime.TryParse(_wert1, New Date) Then
               End If
   ```

   but still not sure if it will work
4. All data that have been read should be encoded in 1252 Codepage.
   this one doesn't really work

```
     Dim ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & TextBox1.Text & ";Extended Properties=""TEXT;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;CODEPAGE=1252"""
```

anyone idea what could be done?

Comment: 1 question at a time please, bundling 4 together makes it too broad and too difficult to post a short answer.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044727/how-to-remove-character-from-a-given-datatable-column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499397/encoding-utf8-string-to-iso-8859-1-string-vb-net

Comment: #3 and #4 are very doable, #2 is too vague without sample data to understand what you are trying to do, #1 *might* be able to be done natively depending on the data, otherwise you may need to add a step.  If you refine the question to something less broad you might get some answers before it is closed

Comment: You should remove the line `Application.DoEvents()` - it can make strange things happen.

Comment: If you need to parse a CSV file, you can use a CSV parser. The [TextFieldParser class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might suffice. Then your program will not be limited by JET.

Comment: i mean i need to read csv files and while reading to replace some characters and convert in the right codepage format as well as recognize data types somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) can do most of what it sounds like you want. [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) might also work, I just haven't worked with it as much.  I wouldn't recommend VB's `TextFieldParser` because it returns a string array rather than typed data.

`OleDB` provides a great way to import, but saving to the database presents a small challenge.  All the loaded rows will have a `RowState` of `Unchanged`. The only way to change that to `Added` is to copy the rows into a new table:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dtCSV.Rows
    dtDest.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray)
Next
```

It will work, but as a result, you will have 2 tables and all those rows loaded at once.  It turns out that using CSVHelper and a simple INSERT query is the most economical - since the records are fetched from an `IEnumerable<T>` only 1 source record will be loaded at a time.  It is also a bit faster than copying rows: about 20% faster on 500k rows.

Note: We have no idea whatsoever what the data looks like other than it is semicolon delimited...and there is apparently a lot of it.

```
Using sr As New StreamReader(CSVFilePath, False),
     csv As New CsvReader(sr)

    ' some CSVHelper config options
    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = True
    csv.Configuration.TrimFields = True
    csv.Configuration.TrimHeaders = True
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";"
    csv.Configuration.IsHeaderCaseSensitive = False
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(Of RandItem.RandItemMap)()

    ' get the file into IEnumerable collection
    Dim csvData = csv.GetRecords(Of OleImportItem)()

    Dim SQL = <sql>
              INSERT INTO RandomData 
                     (Foo, Bar, Cat, Dog...)
              VALUES 
                    (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4...)
            </sql>.Value

    Using dbcon As New OleDbConnection(ACEConnStr)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, dbcon)
            dbcon.Open()

            ' create the parameters
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", OleDbType.Integer)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4", OleDbType.Integer)
            ...
            ' load one item at a time, to save it
            For Each item In csvData
                cmd.Parameters("@p1").Value = item.Foo
                cmd.Parameters("@p2").Value = item.Bar
                cmd.Parameters("@p3").Value = item.Cat
                cmd.Parameters("@p4").Value = item.Dog
                ...
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

I cant give a complete tutorial on how to use it, but in general you create a type (Class) which defines the datatype for each column (here,`RandItem`), the `RandItemMap` is another class which specifies the order of those properties in the file.  In so doing, CSVHelper knows the datatype of each column and will convert for you.

There are several ways to use it, this way is reading one line at a time from the file and immediately saves that item to the database: `csvData = csv.GetRecords(Of OleImportItem)()`  initializes `csvData` as an `IEnumerable(Of RandItem)`, so only *one* item is loaded at a time in the loop which makes it very economical.

In the loop, the code gets a typed `item` from the csv file which is then mapped to the respective parameters and saved.  This is about 20% faster than copying the data to a DataTable in batches and saving; and much less memory intensive since there is only ever 1 item loaded.

---

For smaller csv files, you could use `.ToArray()` or `ToList()` to load the file to a collection.

**Note**  Importing/parsing a text file without headers is a little different than shown, but just as easy.

It sounds like CSVHelper might obviate most issues in your laundry list.

Comment: csv helper is a good approach but i had really bad experience with streamreader because reading large files takes literally hours, is there any way to read files encoded in 1252 and replaced with characters?

Comment: I very seriously doubt streamreader would be the bottleneck.  using the code above, it read in 100k rows into a typed object.  I did not do anything with it since the object was to time StreamReader. However, it does mean an object was created and the non trivial row data parsed and copied into it.  Time elapsed: 903 milliseconds.  But a 1GB file will take time.  That stuff in bullet 2 is something that will also take time - strings are immutable so that one line creates 5 in succession copying bits of data to each.  There is nothing special about 1252 - it is windows default encoding.

Comment: Another test, this time posting all 100k records to a MySql DB in batches of 10k: less than 2 minutes.  More rows will take more time, and what you do to them will take even more time.

Comment: @Sparkm4n do you have any idea how many rows there are in the file?  I was testing something with Dapper and this Q come to mind (since I was testing with the same data).

Comment: I have several large files and the largest one has approx. one million rows

Comment: 250k rows in batches of 25k took only 4 mins.  I didnt have any data transforms though.  Dapper didnt speed it up though